# Cannot establish database connection with selected Hibernate Configuration file. Please verify the database connection details in hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, derby, netbeans-8

My `hibernate.cfg` is as follow

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
  org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">
  jdbc:derby:/home/swapnil/.netbeans-derby/cpos
</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">cpos</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">cpos</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">
  org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
</property>
```

What else I'm missing?
I'm using `Derby Embedded`.
With class file I can establish and access database but it does not working with `Hibernate`
Getting

> Cannot establish database connection with selected Hibernate Configuration file. Please verify the database connection details in hibernate.cfg.xml.

at reverse engineering wizard in `Netbeans IDE`

Comment: What's wrong with that question? Is off-topic?

Comment: [1] Your question is fine, and on topic. I don't understand why it was down voted. [2] Is there no other error or exception beyond the message that is shown in your question?

Comment: No but this connection established in server node. in Netbeans

Comment: You could check whether an error is being written to the NetBeans log: [1] **View > IDE Log** [2] Replicate the connection failure. [3] Update your post with the relevant details if the connection failure causes any new error message(s) to get logged.

Comment: Now I'm using `MySQL Server` instead. Thanks